# Okta API - authn always returns Invalid Session

Tags: api

I'm trying to authenticate an user using the "authn" API:

```
POST MYACCOUNT.oktapreview.com/api/v1/authn
{
  "username": "email@gmail.com",
  "password" : "Password123"
}
```

But this always returns

```
{
    "errorCode": "E0000005",
    "errorSummary": "Invalid session",
    "errorLink": "E0000005",
    "errorId": "oael83e1QQxSNuHOlE0VkqBuA",
    "errorCauses": []
}
```

Any idea why this happens?

When I create the session, I just get a 403 - Forbidden error.

The sessions API works, but I want to use the authn API for a customized login experience.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue was because of the Authorization header in the Okta request.

The Authorization header should be 'Authorization: SSWS API_TOKEN'
Instead, I was just sending 'Authorization: API_TOKEN'

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same `403 - Forbidden` error.
It worked fine in Fiddler but not in my script (Powershell)

URL I used was `http` but the resource was actually on `https`. Fiddler moved me with my header information to the https site. In Powershell I lost the header and got the forbidden error.

So changing the URL to `https` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @paramesh's answer (as it is 100% correct) if you're using postman, what I did was add  'Authorization: SSWS API_TOKEN' as a preset header, and then added it when it was missing.

to do this in postman extension for chrome:
1. Click the 'headers' button far to the right
2. Click 'manage presets'
3. Click 'add' 
4. Fill in the information (if you've imported the okta environment like in their [api test client instructions](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/api_test_client.html)) then it'd look like this: SSWS {{apikey}} 
5. Check headers on other methods, if the authorization header is not there, add it by clicking the 'add preset' button 
I apologize I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment on the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I wasn't using the Okta preview url since I was in a preview environment.

```
https://${org}.okta.com/api/v1/users
```

Should be changed to

```
https://${org}.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending i found fix , the issue is because of following reasons

1. The request url should be https instead of http
2. Authorization header should be SSWS +" "+ api token
3. Request headers should have either accept or content-type is equal to "applicaiton/json"